# При вставке контента из цикла for, в верстку попадает только последний элемент

Tags: javascript

```
var content = $('.quiz-form-content .row');     
element = document.createElement("div");
                var elements = [];
                classname = "quiz-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4";

                var el_img = document.createElement("img");
                var el_descr = document.createElement("div");
                for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
                    element = $(element).addClass(classname).attr('data-variant', step2_content[i][0]);

                    $(el_img).addClass("quiz-item-image img-fluid").attr("src", step2_content[i][1]);
                    element.append(el_img);
                    $(el_descr).addClass("quiz-item-description").text(step2_content[i][2]);
                    element.append(el_descr);

                }



                $(content).append(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //var el_img = document.createElement("img");
        //var el_descr = document.createElement("div");
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
          var el_img = document.createElement("img");
          var el_descr = document.createElement("div");
```

Comment: Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, спасибо

Comment: @Bumerang37 Пожалуйста. Успехов!